# XSLT - Using for-each-group for following siblings

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I've xml like follows,

```
<doc>
    <h1>header 1</h1>
    <p>para</p>
    <p>para</p>

    <h1>header 2</h1>
    <p>para</p>
    <h2>header 2 sub h1</h2>
    <h2>header 2 sub h2</h2>

    <h1>header 3</h1>
    <p>para</p>
    <p>para</p>

    <h1>header 4</h1>
    <h2>header 4 sub h1</h2>
    <p>para</p> 

</doc>
```

what I need is get all `<h1>` and `<h2>` nodes respectively and create an unordered list with links,

so the desired output is,

```
<doc>
   <ul>
      <li><h1><a href="page-header1-1">header 1</a></h1></li>

      <li><h1><a href="page-header1-2">header 2</a></h1></li>
         <ul> 
            <li><h2><a href="page-header2-1">header 2 sub h1</a></h2></li>
            <li><h2><a href="page-header2-2">header 2 sub h2</a></h2></li>
         </ul>

      <li><h1><a href="page-header1-3">header 3</a></h1></li>

      <li><h1><a href="page-header1-4">header 4 sub h1</a></h1></li>
         <ul>
            <li><h2><a href="page-header2-3">zz</a></h2></li>
         </ul>
   </ul>
</doc>
```

I've written following xsl to achieve this task,

```
<xsl:template match="doc">
        <div>
            <ul>
                <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-starting-with="h1">
                    <li><a href="page-header1-{count(preceding::h1)+1}"> <xsl:copy-of select="."/></a> </li>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="page-header2-{count(preceding::h2)+1}"><xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()[self::h2]"/></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </xsl:for-each-group>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>
```

my output is looks like this,

```
 <doc>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="page-header1-1"><h1>header 1</h1></a></li>
            <ul><li><a href="page-header2-1"/></li></ul>

        <li><a href="page-header1-2"><h1>header 2</h1></a></li>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="page-header2-1">
                        <h2>header 2 sub h1</h2>
                        <h2>header 2 sub h2</h2>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>

        <li><a href="page-header1-3"><h1>header 3</h1></a></li>
            <ul><li><a href="page-header2-3"/></li></ul>

        <li><a href="page-header1-4"><h1>header 4</h1></a></li>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="page-header2-3">
                        <h2>header 4 sub h1</h2>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
    </ul>
</doc>
```

I've identified 2 errors there

1) it adds empty `<a href="page-header2-x"></a>` values where there are no following siblings for `<h1>`s. (see the results of 1st and 3rd `<h1>` s)

2) `<a>` are not separately added to `<h2>` nodes. but it adds `<a>` to group of `<h2>`s which are consecutively placed. (see under 2nd `<h1>` in the result) But I need to add `<a>` to separately for every `<h2>`.

I've used `<xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()[self::h2]"/>` to get the `<h2>` s and it seems it returns all `<h2>` as a group but not returns separately.

Can anyone suggest me a method to sort out this problem..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `<ul>
                        <li><a href="page-header2-{count(preceding::h2)+1}"><xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()[self::h2]"/></a></li>
                    </ul>` to

`<xsl:variable name="h2" select="current-group()[self::h2]"/>
<xsl:if test="$h2">
  <ul>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$h2"/>
  </ul>
</xsl:if>`

and add a template
`<xsl:template match="h2">
   <li><a href="page-header2-{position()"><xsl:copy-of select="."/></a></li>
</xsl:template>`